# Preencher select do html com valores do banco de dados

Tags: php, pdo, aplicação-web, php-7, html-select

Bom dia, sou iniciante no php e estou criando um projeto pessoal de cadastro de pessoas. Tenho uma tela que lista todos os usuários e ao clicar em alterar usuário, ele me retorna os valores do usuário no banco, porém ele não me retorna o sexo do usuário. Quero saber como faço para ele preencher automaticamente o select do html de acordo com o valor do banco de dados.

Comment: É importante colocar na pergunta o código e quais os valores que vem do banco relacionado ao sexo.

Answer (score 1):

Dentro do select que você tem as opções você deve fazer um if comparando com a informação de retorno do banco. Ex: Considerando que você monte um select com uma tabela de genero com os campos tipo={M,F} e nome={Masculino,  Feminino} ou dentro de um array. E no cadastro da pessoa possua um campo genero que você armazena o tipo.

```
<select name='genero'>
  <?php foreach($generos as $genero):?>
     <option value="<?=$genero['tipo']?>"
     <?php if ($genero['tipo'] == $pessoa['genero']) {?> selected="selected" <?php }?>>
     <?= $genero['nome']?></option>
  <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```